# What is the difference between shop and store?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I mean when we should say:shop and store.

For example:

> - [1] *  He is working at a barbershop.
> - [2] *  He is working at a barber store.

Why we say coffee shop and not coffee store.

Why we say department store and not department shop?

Comment: Barbershop has a specific meaning. There's no such thing as a barber store.

Comment: I don't think it's really the same question. The linked question is about when you say "go shopping" versus "going to the store", while this question is about the difference between the nouns "shop" and "store". Yes, there's some overlap, but not really the same.

Comment: It's not the same question.

Comment: @ ColleenV  she asked about:                when should she says :I am going to the shop and I am going to the store but me, I am asking about:.                               Why we say barbershop and not barber store.                                                      Why we say coffee shop and not coffee store.?                                                                Why we say department store and not department shop?

Comment: @Jay It's not the same question as written, but the answers given the lack of context, should be helpful. If the question is edited to explain why the answers to the duplicate question aren't helpful, we could probably reopen it.

Comment: @ColleenV I read the answer,it not clear for me.please could you reopen it.